Matlab 5G NTN BER
I’m trying to calculate BER for different txPower in this model: https://www.mathworks.com/help/satcom/ug/nr-ntn-pdsch-throughput.html
But BER is always near 0.5. Can someone help me to solve this problem.
I’ve tried to calculate all bits and incorrect bits and than devide incorrect bits by all bits. But it always ≈ 0.5. The problem may be with the phase, but there is CPE Correction. There are Doppler compensation and synchronization.
